# How to append to the path in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

I have a file at "/downloads/some.file", and I want that added to my path.  How is this accomplished in ubuntu?

Comment: Don't add your downloads directory to `$PATH`, it'll bite you sooner or later. Create a dedicated `~/bin` or something.

Answer (score 3):

In your `~/.profile` file, append to the exported path.

```
export PATH="/downloads:$PATH"
```

Comment: Tried this, and still unable to access it from the path.. I restarted the terminal, do I need to do more?

Comment: @coffee .profile is loaded upon login. Try logging out and back in to your system. Putting it in .profile makes it global to your login and not just an invoked bash shell.